# Baffling c# compiler CS0234 error on Windows 10 only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, windows-10, google-shopping-api

When migrating a working Visual Studio 2010 solution targeting .Net 4.0 from Windows 7 to Windows 10 environment, I encountered a CS0234 compilation error: **The type or namespace name 'My-Namespace-Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**.

The trigger of the error appeared to be references to types in 3rd party libraries https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2/1.16.0.636 in one of my libraries where 'My-Namespace-Name' was also defined. The error message occurred when compiling another library which linked in this library. The 3rd party libraries were installed using NuGet and supported .Net 4.0.

I created a simple test solution with two class libraries to demonstrate the problem. The 3rd party libraries were installed for the 1st library. I declared a single variable of type **ShoppingContentService** from the 3rd party libraries in the 1st library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2;
using Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Requests;
using log4net;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        //comment out the following declaration the compilation error goes away
        private static ShoppingContentService s_service;

        public static void Method1()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd library references the 1st library. The error was reproduced when compiling the solution pointing to the **using ClassLibrary1;** statement:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary2\Class2.cs   5   7   ClassLibrary2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public static void Method2()
        {
            Class1.Method1();
        }
    }
}
```

The solution file can be downloaded from: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiZZDdaejTrJrz_9Ayngj9iTopzz

Switching to VS 2017 does not resolve the problem and neither does changing the target framework to .Net 4.5.

Thanks in advance for taking a look into this issue and any light you can shed on it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would think that the error message is spot on with _"are you missing [...] an assembly reference?"_ ...

Comment: @elgonzo no, he had the reference, what he was missing was looking at the warnings that where also shown.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the other warning you get and it gives you a hint at what is going wrong

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ClassLibrary2   D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary2\Class2.cs    5   Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'Class1.s_service' is never used  ClassLibrary1   D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs    17  Active
Warning     All projects referencing ClassLibrary1.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.  ClassLibrary2           
Warning     The primary reference "D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". ClassLibrary2           
Warning     The primary reference "D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". ClassLibrary2           
Warning     The primary reference "D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "D:\Users\Tami\Downloads\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". ClassLibrary2
```

The bottom 3 warnings tell you that `ClassLibrary2` can't refrence `ClassLibrary1` due to indirect dependencies, the 4th from the bottom warning starts you on the right path on how to fix it.

You will need to to have the following in your `packages.config` for your `ClassLibrary2` project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Now you will be able to reference `ClassLibrary1` without warnings or errors (other than the `The field 'Class1.s_service' is never used` one)

---

P.S.

> Switching to VS 2017 does not resolve the problem and neither does changing the target framework to .Net 4.5.

Actually had you removed the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package and all its dependencies (like you are supposed to) after you upgraded to .NET 4.5 it would have also fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Scott!  In our solution, the warnings also appeared on Windows 7 but the compilation completed without problem so it didn't occur to me that they were related to the error. After adding the libraries to the packages.config file, the compilation problem went away in the sample but not the original solution which only saw the disappearance of the warnings. The Win 10 machine had VS 2017 first and now it has both VS 2017 and 2010 and there is a v4.X .NetFramework directory. I will try to see if I can repro the problem again by making changes to the sample.